# boost build: disable -Weffc++ per module

Tags: c++, gcc, boost-build, bjam

I use boost build for a large project that is divided into different subprojects.
Here the jamroot file:

```
project
    : requirements
    <variant>debug:<define>DEBUG
    <variant>release:<define>NDEBUG
    <variant>debug:<cxxflags>-Weffc++
    <include>.
    :
    ;

use-project ...
use-project ...
...

build-project ...
build-project ...
...
```

One subproject includes automatically generated code that isn't that good in code style. So I would like to disable tie -Weffc++ directive for this subproject.
Declaring -Weffc++ per subproject is possible but I don't really like this solution, because I want to have -Weffc++ everywhere BUT in the (really few) subprojects I disable it.

Is there a possibility in boost build to disable this  directive per subproject? Or is there a gcc compiler option I can add with another  in the subproject and that will disable the already specified -Weffc++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate any Gcc warning option with the `no-` prefix: `g++ -Wno-effc++`. Define that for the subprojects you want to exclude, and it should work as long as subprojects' options are added to the command line *after* the defaults.

Comment: Extension: When you include the headers path of the subproject not with the gcc option "-I/path/to/subproject", but with "-isystem /path/to/subproject", the warnings in the included headers also will be ignored, because the headers are seen as system headers.